# Jackson XML deserialization, InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "time"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, json-deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have a DTO like this:

```
package ...;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class RootDto {
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    LocalDateTime time;

    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "times")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "time")
    List<InternalTimeDto> times;

    ...
}
```

```
package ...;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class InternalTimeDto {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    LocalDateTime time;
}
```

As I understand it, the problem is that the `time` field and the elements of the `times` field have the same name. Is there a way to resolve the conflict without renaming one `time` to something else? In theory, there should be no conflict at all, since the `time` field and the list items are at different levels.
XML example:

```
<root>
    <time>2020-11-18 12:34</time>
    <times>
        <time id="5">2020-11-18 10:00</time>
        <time id="6">2020-11-17 15:30</time>
    </times>

    ...
</root>
```

I found a couple of answers, but they solve the problem when two different objects with the same name are on the same level.

JSON is used too:

```
{
  "time": "2020-11-18 12:34",
  "times": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "time": "2020-11-18 10:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "time": "2020-11-17 15:30"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the erase the conflict due to the multiple defined property `time`  preserving your xml format is to create a `Times` class wrapping your `List<InternalTimeDto>` times :

```
public class Times {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "time")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    List<InternalTimeDto> times;   
}
```

So your `RootDto` class can be rewritten in this way:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class RootDto {
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    LocalDateTime time;

    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Times times; //<-- times field instead of List<InternalTimeDto> times 
}
```

Your `InternalTimeDto` class needs the `JacksonXmlText` annotation for the `time` field:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class InternalTimeDto {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    Long id;

    @JacksonXmlText
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    LocalDateTime time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for XML now. Unfortunately, to keep things simple, I didn't mention that JSON is also used. I have updated the question.

Comment: @YaroslavTarasenko You are welcome. Using my classes In the json case in the `RootDto` replace the Times class with `List<InternalTimeDto> times`, otherwise if you want to use the same code for xml and json the only alternative is to write a custom deserializer for `Times` class.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a custom deserializer is the only solution in my case. Thank you.